# select Kendo ui grid row from controller

Tags: model-view-controller, kendo-ui, radio-button, kendo-grid

My first problem is : I use kendo grid with Single Select mode and I need when view loaded for the first time, the first row is selected, in other words, i want to select the first kendo grid row programatically.
moreover other problem is i insert radiobutton column in that grid , and i want synchronize
radiobutton select with row select , in other words, i want that when user select row,it causes it's radiobutton Selected
 Please help me
tnx
  this is the code:

```
   @(Html.Kendo().Grid<CommonData.Domain.LegalEntityPhone>()
.Name("SMSGrid")
.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:800px;" })
.Selectable(selectable =>
             selectable.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single).Type(GridSelectionType.Row))

.Columns(columns =>
    {
       columns.Bound(c => c.Id)
    .Title(" ")
    .ClientTemplate(" <input type='radio' id='Approve' name='chkApprove' />");

       columns.Bound(c => c.Number)
    .Title("Destination")
    .HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: center;" })
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: center; });

       columns.Bound(c => c.CityCode)
    .Title("City Code")
    .Width(30)
    .HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: center" })
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center;width:30px" });


        columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); }).Width(150);
        })

.Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
    .Events(events => events.Change("OnChange"))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Model(model =>
        {
                       model.Id(p => p.Id);
                       model.Field(p => p.Id).Editable(false);
        })
    .Read(read => read.Action("LegalEntityPhoneInfo_Read", "Message"))
    .Update(update => update.Action("LegalEntityPhoneInfo_Update", "Message"))
                    )
                )
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as making the row selected in the controller because the Grid is all created on the client. You can use the **[dataBound](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#databound)** event to make the first row selected.

e.g.

```
$(function(){
     $('#GridName').data().kendoGrid.bind('dataBound',function(e){
          this.select(this.tbody.find('>tr:first'));
     }) 
})
```

Or use **one** instead of **bind** to make the row selected only when the page is loaded, not each time when the Grid is rebound - sort,filter, etc. Check [documentation](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/widget#one) for more info.

Comment: thanks for your replay ,but i don't know how to use your jquery fanction ,Could you Explain more? how can i use it with kendo grid?

Answer (score 0):

If you are unfamiliar with jQuery, I highly recommend you take an online free tutorial from  http://jqueryair.com/.
Assuming your project is referencing the jQuery script in your _Layout page, all you should have to do is add an Event handler for Databound to the grid:

```
.Events(events => events.DataBound("Grid_Databound"))
```

Then just paste this script onto the page:

```
<script> 

function Grid_Databound() {

var grid = $("#MyGridName").data("kendoGrid");
row = grid.tbody.find(">tr:not(.k-grouping-row)").eq(0);
grid.select(row);
        }
</script>
```

I'm sure the same script that zeinad added would work as well, always more than one way to skin a cat. As far as making the radio button show selected if the row is selected, I think if you watched the tutorial I mentioned, you should be able to figure it out. Post back if you need more help.

Comment: thanks for your guidance, i watch the tutorial , that is good .I know jquery but not very very well.In your code, you use #MyGridName selector but in my code i dynamically name grid like this  .Name("SMSGrid" + (string)Session["FileId"]), How can i use your code?